# Problem with ajax paging request in Asp.Net MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paging

I have implemented ajax on paging but my problem is when i navigate on paging and go to page 1 then on page 2 after that if i press backspace it went to the last page from where it comes instead of going to page 1. I want to know how should i implement paging like stackoverflow have. Further i have noticed that my url doesnt change on paging it remains like Home/Index when im on 1st page or 2nd page or any other page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to use the browser forward/back button while using ajax you will need to use something like a jquery history plugin e.g. http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/. There are plenty out there just google "jquery history"